# Не отрабатывает событие javascript на элементе <select>

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

Есть фрагмент в jsp

```
<select size="5" multiple="multiple" title="РЦ" id="dcsel"
                name="dcenters" align="right">
                <%...
%>
            </select>
```

элемент select - выпадающий список.

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на элемент select загружался javascript

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('load', function(){
        $("#dcsel").on( 'click', function() { // не реагирует
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : defaultPath + 'reports/treatmentElementsPage',
                cache : false,
                processData : false,
                type : 'POST',
                contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                success: function(response) {
                    $.each(response, function(index, item) {
                        console.log(item);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `dcsel.focus = function(){ желаемый код}`

Comment: не сработало. я в отладчике щелкаю по форме, выпадает список, но на сроке  dcsel.focus = function() { дебаг не останавливается.

Comment: ой, нужно написать `onfocus`

Comment: не работает увы(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте событие change на select

```js
$("#dcsel").on('change', function() {
        var v = $(this).val()
        $('body').css('background', v);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select size="5" multiple="multiple" title="РЦ" id="dcsel" name="dcenters" align="right">
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: так событие `change` генерируется по окончанию изменения значения, когда это значение уже зафиксировано. А нужно `при нажатии`